# capture exit code of child script called via ssh from parent script using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have a child script called deployment.sh and parent script called deloy_base.sh. From parent deploy_base.sh, iam invoking the child script via ssh on other server. Actually child script is doing the deployment process. If any commands failed in the child script, error status should be sent to the parent script, so that i can send email based on the success or failure error code from child script.

Now irrespective of any command failed in child script, its always going to success block. Please help.

```
 ssh user@10.0.0.1 "/home/scripts/deployment.sh" DEV 2>&1  | tee /home/release/DEV.log
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
    `mail -s "DEPLOYMENT FAILED" -a /home/DEV.log
     -r "Deployment_Log@example.com" user@example.com > /dev/null 2>&1`
    else
   `mail -s "DEPLOYMENT SUCCESS" -a /home/DEV.log
     -r "Deployment_Log@example.com" user@example.com  > /dev/null 2>&1`
    Fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`man bash`

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command,
>   unless the **pipefail** option is enabled. If **pipefail** is enabled, the
>   pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command
>   to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

In your case `$?` is the exit status of `tee`, but

```
set -o pipefail
```

solves the problem.